# round down to nearest 5 mintues php mysqli

Tags: php, mysql, time, rounding

I"m trying to get this time code to round down to the nearest time
example if the time listed is 10:28, then i want it to show 10:25

What I have is (the time modify is required)

```
<?php 
include('../../database/2ndconnection.php');

$sql="SELECT * FROM raid ORDER BY TimeRecord DESC LIMIT 1";
$result=mysqli_query($dbcon,$sql);

while($rows=mysqli_fetch_array($result)){
    $dateStr = $rows['TimeRecord'];

    $pst = new \DateTime($dateStr);
    $pst->modify("-3 hours");

    $est = new \DateTime($dateStr);
} ?>

PST: <?php echo $pst->format('H:i'); ?>
<br>EST: <?php echo $est->format('H:i'); ?>
```

thanks in advance for your help

Answer (score 1):

Insert this:

```
<?php
$currentMinutes = $time->format('i');
$minutesToSubtract = $currentMinutes % 5;
$time = $time->sub(new DateInterval('M' . $minutesToSubtract));
?>
```

`$currentMinutes` will hold the current number of minutes, using `%`, you can compute the minutes that need to be subtracted, and afterwards you subtract them through the `sub` function

It could be integrated into your code as following:

```
<?php 
include('../../database/2ndconnection.php');

$sql="SELECT * FROM raid ORDER BY TimeRecord DESC LIMIT 1";
$result=mysqli_query($dbcon,$sql);

while($rows=mysqli_fetch_array($result)){
    $dateStr = $rows['TimeRecord'];

    $pst = new \DateTime($dateStr);
    $pst->modify("-3 hours");

    $est = new \DateTime($dateStr);
}

$currentMinutes = $pst->format('i');
$minutesToSubtract = $currentMinutes % 5;
$pst = $pst->sub(new DateInterval('M' . $minutesToSubtract));

?>

PST: <?php echo $pst->format('H:i'); ?>
<br>EST: <?php echo $est->format('H:i'); ?>
```

Comment: maybe add some explanations?

Comment: Well, I used variables that are easy to read and only very basic PHP functions, but for helping out I added them...

Comment: I've seen similar to that in a few places but every time i try to add it to my current working code, nothing works, either it doesnt make any change at all or it breaks the page. Can anyone help me alter my current code?

Comment: Did you try using my code? Would you share the changed code?

Comment: Problem is I have no clue where in the code to put it, :/ especially since none if the $variables are similar to mine. I'm still learning php and while your functions are followable in the snippet you wrote, This is my first project modifying DateTime so i'm kinda noob :( hense why I came here for help after searching google all night

Comment: See my edited answer. You can use whatever variable you like to use, and as you didn't specify whether you want to round `$pst` or `$est`, I abstracted it a bit in my first answer

Comment: thankyou for your time to try to help me. Eventually it will be both, but once i can get one to work I probably could do both.  I put the code in as you showed above, it broke the page again :/

Comment: its not showing me anything I tried to view the source code and only the thing it shows is the style codes. it isnt even loading the plain text thats not between the php  <?php ?>

Comment: Then you should have a look at your servers error log

Comment: the log stupidly is empty so I tried putting the change in 1 line at a time 
first two lines do not break it. only 
    $pst = $pst->sub(new DateInterval('M' . $minutesToSubtract));
 breaks it

Comment: Try adding a slash before DateInterval

Comment: tried this         `$pst = $pst->sub(new \DateInterval('M' . $minutesToSubtract));`           no change